# Beautiful pigeonhole Olympiad problem

Tags: combinatorics

You have a set of disjoint arcs on a circle of circumference $1$ with sum of lengths greater than $1-\frac{1}{n}$.

Show that there is a regular $n$-gon such that each of its vertices lies on one of the arcs.

Comment: Is the set of arcs finite or infinite?

Comment: Doesn't matter: if the set of arcs is infinite, there's still a finite subset of arcs with sum of lengths greater than $1-\frac1n$.

Comment: I dont know how to show this, but if you can collect all the uncovered segments, the maximum total length is $\frac 1{n}$, which is the arclength between adjacent vertices of the $n$ gon

Comment: take the complementary of that set of arcs (again a set of arcs). take one of the obtained arcs, rotating it by $2\pi/n$ doesn't change what regular $n$-gons it forbids. and one arc can be splitted in two parts, and only one can be rotated, again it doesn't change anything. finally, rotate them all in the same $[0,2\pi/n[$ part of the circle

Answer (score 3):

Average the number of covered vertices over the possible positions of the $n$-gon. The result is greater than $n(1-\frac1n)=n-1$. Since the number of covered vertices is an integer, it follows that there is at least one position with $n$ vertices covered.

Comment: How do you know the average is greater than $n(1-1/n)$?

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou: Because the sum of the lengths is greater than $1-\frac1n$, so as you rotate the $n$ vertices around the circle they're each covered more than $1-\frac1n$ of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Assume a regular n sided polygon at an arbitrary position and rotate it about centre of circle through angle (2*π)/n then atleast at some point of time during rotation all vertices should be on the given set of arcs if not atleast 1/n length of circumference is not covered by given set of arcs

Answer (score 0):

Split the circle into $n$ equally-sized arcs of size $1/n$. And then line them up one on top of each other over the interval $[0, 1/n)$.

If there's a point in $[0, 1/n)$ such that all $n$ corresponding points in the circle are covered by our disjoint arc set, then those $n$ vertices form a regular $n$-gon on the original circle (as they are spaced $1/n$ apart).

But by pigeonhole there must be such a covered point.

---

Note: if we want to be extra rigorous here we can discretize: split the circle into $M$ parts with $n | M$; each $1/n$ arc is split into $M/n$ parts.

For large enough $M$, we will find that at least one full $1/M$-length part is covered in all $n$.

Proof: here each interval of length $\ell_i$ covers at least $\ell_i M - 2$ intervals. Now let $\varepsilon = \sum_i \ell_i - (1-1/n)$. Then the number $N$ of covered intervals is $\ge (\sum_i \ell_i) M - 2k = (1-1/n + \varepsilon)M - 2k$. Since $\varepsilon$ and $k$ are just constants, we can pick $M$ big enough so that the total number of covered intervals is $> (1-1/n)M$, and we can now apply usual discrete pigeonhole.